# MSTest data driven rows are cast to ints

Tags: c#, datasource, mstest, data-driven

I have a data driven test (using MSTest) that has inputs that look like this:

ValuesToInput,ExpectedValue
0,0
00,00
000,000
0000,000
00000,000
000000,000

When I pull those out of my TestContext they are just 0.  It has converted my string of 0000 to an int and gives me 0.

How can I make it give me my values as strings?

NOTE: My test method is setup like this:

```
[TestCategory("CodedUI"), DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "MyCvsFile.csv", "MyCvsFile#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem("DataDriven\\MyCvsFile.csv"), TestMethod]
public void DoMyTest()
{
    // My Test Stuff here

}
```

Comment: @Matthew - I updated my question to show that

Comment: CSV strings are `"000","000"`

Comment: @HenkHolterman -  We tried that and it did not work.  We did get this to work finally: "0""0""0".  But that is really tedious to do for all input.